# Como consultar aniversariante do dia e do mes em SQL no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, data

Eu vi alguns exemplos aqui, e tentei reproduzi-los, porém, no Oracle não aceita operadores como `MONTH`, então não tive sucesso.

```
SELECT nome from aluno where month(datanascimento) = month(now());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No **Oracle** você pode usar o [`EXTRACT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

```
 SELECT nome 
  FROM aluno
  WHERE extract(month from datanascimento) = extract(month from sysdate)
```

Aqui um exemplo funcionando: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8e1e/1)

Answer (score 5):

Complementando a [resposta do @Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/321669/112052), uma das maneiras de se fazer é usar [`EXTRACT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm). Como você quer "consultar aniversariante do dia e do mês", deve extrair estes campos (dia e mês) da data de nascimento e compará-los com a data atual (`sysdate`):

```
SELECT nome FROM aluno
WHERE extract(month from datanascimento) = extract(month from sysdate)
      AND extract(day from datanascimento) = extract(day from sysdate)
```

---

Outra maneira é obter o dia e mês de uma só vez, usando [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm), que converte a data para `VARCHAR`, usando algum formato específico.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924), podemos usar o formato `MM-DD` (`MM` corresponde ao mês e `DD` ao dia). Assim, a query ficaria desta maneira:

```
SELECT nome FROM aluno
WHERE to_char(datanascimento, 'MM-DD') = to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD')
```

Por exemplo, para a data de hoje (11 de agosto), `to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD')` retorna `08-11` (não importando qual é o ano). Por isso, se a data de nascimento também for 11 de agosto (mesmo que seja em outro ano), o resultado de `to_char` também será `08-11`.

---

### Anos bissextos

Independente da solução escolhida, ainda há um caso especial a se considerar: se uma pessoa nasceu em **29 de fevereiro de 2016** (ou 29 de fevereiro de qualquer outro ano bissexto), por exemplo. Como o seu sistema detectará que é aniversário desta pessoa em anos que não são bissextos?

Se você usar as queries acima, seu sistema só detectará o aniversário deste usuário em anos bissextos (pois nos outros anos não existe 29 de fevereiro).

Por isso em anos que não são bissextos, você deverá tomar alguma decisão:

- considerar que o aniversário é 28 de fevereiro ou 1 de março (*conheço pessoas que nasceram em 29 de fevereiro, e em anos não-bissextos elas comemoram o aniversário em um desses dias*)
- não fazer nada (sabendo que estes usuários não terão o aniversário detectado todos os anos)

Segue um exemplo de query que detecta o aniversário do usuário no dia 28 de fevereiro, mas somente em anos não-bissextos (se o ano for bissexto, o aniversário é detectado normalmente no dia 29):

```
SELECT a.nome
FROM 
 (SELECT aluno.*,
  case -- verifica se o ano atual é bissexto
    when mod(extract(year from sysdate), 400) = 0
         OR
         (mod(extract(year from sysdate), 100) <> 0
          AND mod(extract(year from sysdate), 4) = 0)
    then 1
    else 0
  end as ano_bissexto
  FROM aluno) a
WHERE
  to_char(a.datanascimento, 'MM-DD') = to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD')
  OR
  -- nasceu em 29 de fevereiro, ano atual não é bissexto e hoje é 28 de fevereiro
  (to_char(a.datanascimento, 'MM-DD') = '02-29' AND a.ano_bissexto = 0
   AND to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD') = '02-28')
```

Lembrando que a [regra do ano bissexto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) é:

- se o ano for múltiplo de 100, só é bissexto se for múltiplo de 400
- se não for múltiplo de 100, só é bissexto se for múltiplo de 4